# Why is $\Delta^0$ not decaying weakly?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, weak-interaction

Given the lower decay I wonder why it happens this way. Wouldn't it be possible to decay via a weak process as well?

[image: decay]

Comment: Isn’t this just the fastest decay channel, not the only one? Strong implies fast; weak implies slow.

Comment: Hint: what's the typical lifetime for a weak decay?

Comment: Have a look http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/delta.html

Comment: I take back my earlier comment. The experimental signature would be the charged lepton (we'd be looking at $\Delta^0 \to p^+ + W^- \to p^+ + l^- + \nu_l$). The rate will be small because of the difference in coupling constants and the mass difference being much smaller than the W mass, but at least you'll have something to *look* for.

Comment: thanks, so it is possible indeed. Why is it small due to the coupling constants? Because two processes are involved in general?

Comment: Yes the couplings, that is why the interaction is called weak. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html

Answer (score 1):

Particles can decay via three different kinds of processes, depending on which force is involved. These processes all have different time scales:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{weak interactions:}\quad & \tau \approx 10^{-10}\text{ s}\\
\text{electromagnetic interactions:}\quad & \tau \approx 10^{-18}\text{ s}\\
\text{strong interactions:}\quad & \tau \approx 10^{-23}\text{ s}
\end{align}
$$

As you can see, the strong processes happen really fast. So if a particle *can* decay via a strong process it probably will.